# Duda con el literal b de este ejercicio

Tags: java, poo

Muy buenas a toda la comunidad soy nuevo y con ganas de aprender en java.
Bueno mi duda radica en el literal b, mi codigo lo tengo de esta forma.

En una clase llamada Persona se tienen dos métodos y una variable, la variable se llama 
tipoBaile y es privada.
a. El primer método es público y se llamará bailar y tendrá un parámetro, la función de 
éste será mostrar en pantalla el mensaje “Yo bailo” y concatenar la variable que 
recibirá en el parámetro el cual será capturado desde teclado. Ejemplo del mensaje 
“Yo bailo salsa”
b. El segundo método debe ser privado y su función será capturar el valor de la variable.
c. Cree un constructor por omisión que inicialice la variable tipoBaile = ”salsa” y que 
invoque el método bailar.
d. Cree un constructor personalizado para que reciba como parámetro la variable de la 
clase.
Cree la clase que contiene el método main e invoque los métodos.

```
import java.util.*;

class persona(){
  private String tipoBaile;

  public void bailar(String genero){
    System.out.println("yo bailo"+genero);
  }

  private void bailar(){
    System.out.println();
  }

  public persona(){
    tipoBaile="salsa";
    bailar(tipoBaile);
  }

  public persona(String tipoBaile){
    this.tipoBaile=tipoBaile;
  }
}

class Demopersona{
  public static void main(String[]HD){

    persona per1 = new persona();



  }
}
```

stoy trabajando con constructores como pueden ver.
No se si estare mal y espero que me corrijan.

Comment: Podrias mirar [ask]? el codigo siemrpe debe ir como texto y no como imagen. En tu codigo no hay ningun literal b, de que estas hablando?

Comment: Oops! Perdon por eso.

Comment: presiona el boton [edit]. Saca la imagen, y copia tu codigo.

Comment: y ahora vuelvo a preguntar. Que es el literal b?

Comment: Creo que ahora si sale el ejercicio.

Comment: y que es el literal b? en tu codigo no hay ninguna variable que se llame b.

Comment: Mis disculpas por todo el enredo con el post.

Comment: Tranquilo.. te vamos a ayudar a dejarlo bonito y obtener una respuesta.. pero se claro.. no se que es el literal b. te referis al punto b de tu ejercicio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso amigo BernalHD te recomiendo organizar bien tu código.

Este sería tu código organizado:

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.*;


/* a.-El primer método es público y se llamará bailar y tendrá un parámetro, 
la función de éste será mostrar en pantalla el mensaje “Yo bailo” y 
concatenar la variable que recibirá en el parámetro el cual será capturado 
desde teclado. Ejemplo del mensaje “Yo bailo salsa” 

b. El segundo método debe ser privado y su función será capturar el valor de
la variable. 

c. Cree un constructor por omisión que inicialice la variable 
tipoBaile = ”salsa” y que invoque el método bailar. 

d. Cree un constructor personalizado para que reciba como parámetro la variable 
de la clase. Cree la clase que contiene el método main e invoque los métodos.*/

public class Persona {

private String tipoBaile;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);



//primero debe ir tu constructor 
public Persona() { 
    this.tipoBaile = "salsa";
    bailar(tipoBaile);
}
//esta es la opcion d
public Persona(String entrada) { 
    entrada=ObtenerTeclado();
    bailar(entrada);
}

//despues los metodos

//en este hacemos lo de la parte a
public void bailar(String msj){
    System.out.println("Yo bailo "+msj);
}


//aqui hacemos lo de la parte b
private String ObtenerTeclado(){
    String entrada = scanner.nextLine();
    return entrada;
}


}
```

Después creas otra clase y listo:

```
package javaapplication1;


public class Demo {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     //aqui es donde creas otra clase y ehecurtas el metodo main 
     Persona persona = new Persona();
     Persona persona2 = new Persona("");
 }

}
```

Comment: Genial, bueno como ves soy nuevo y aqui aprendiendo un poco de programación.

Comment: NO te preocupes yo no tengo mucho tiempo e esto igual y siento que aquí aprenderemos mas :D saludos no se te olvide votar para q

Answer (score 1):

La parte b dice que debes crear un método privado que obtenga el tipo de baile que se ingresara por teclado.

```
Private void queBailo
{
tipoBaile = System.console().readLine();
bailar(tipoBaile);
}
```

Comment: Ah! Esa parte no conocia como se hacia.

Comment: Pense que se usaba set y get, asumiendo que usaria la variable privada.